# Laravel 5.3 impossible to put script on view (autocomplete field)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-5.3

I’m currently working on Laravel 5.3 for my internship.
And as you guessed, I have an annoying issue let me explain it:

On a page, I have to put an « autocomplete » field but It’s not working at all.
I have this error I can’t solve:

```
[Vue warn]: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed. app.js:139
```

Furthermore, I need to keep the larvel « template » like the top bar with the login name, etc…

I tried a lot of solutions found on the internet but nothing worked.
I’m totally desperate, do you have any solutions ?
ps: Sorry for the awful grammar, I'm french and I'm learning, thanks for your comprehension.

***selectcr.blade.php***

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Selection de Compte-Rendu</div>

                <div class="panel-body"> Selectionnez le client:

                  <input  id="intervenant-name"  type="text" class="form-control pd-l-50" placeholder="Recherche par nom d'entreprise">

                  <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-1.12.4.js')}}"></script>

                  <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>

                  <script>
                  (function () {
                      src = "/prefcard/maker-search-intervenant";
                      $("#intervenant-name").autocomplete({
                          source: function (request, response)
                          {
                              $.ajax({
                                  url: src,
                                          dataType: "json",
                                          data:
                                          {
                                              term: request.term
                                          },
                                          success: function (data)
                                          {
                                              response(data);
                                          }
                              });
                          },
                          min_length: 2,
                          select: function (event, ui)
                          {
                                  //console.log(ui.item.value);return false;
                              var test = ui.item.value ? ui.item.value : '';
                              if (test != '')
                              {
                                  var url = '/prefcard/maker-search-intervenant';
                                  var formAutocomplete = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
                                          '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">' +
                                          '<input type="text" name="term" value="' + ui.item.value + '" />' +
                                          '</form>');
                                  $('body').append(formAutocomplete);
                                  formAutocomplete.submit();
                              }
                            }
                      });
                  })();
                  </script>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@yield('javascript')

@endsection
```

***SelectCRController.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class SelectCRController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('selectcr');
    }

    public function searchIntervenant(Request $request) {

        $query = $request->get('term', '');

        $results = DB::table('intervenant')->where('intervenantEntreprise', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('intervenantFonction', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->take(5)->get();

        $data = array();
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data[] = array('value' => $result->intervenantEntreprise . ' ' . $result->intervenantEmail, 'id' => $result->id);
        }
        if (count($data))
            return $data;
        else
            return ['value' => 'No Result Found', 'id' => ''];
    }

    public function postSearchIntervenant(Request $request) {
        //Do whatever you want to search accordingly name and then return
        return view('dashboard')->with('intervenant', $intervenant);
    }
}
```

***web.php***

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {return view('welcome');});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/configuration', 'ConfigurationController@index');

Route::get('/selectcr', 'SelectCRController@index');
Route::get('/prefcard/maker-search-intervenant', 'SelectCRController@searchIntervenant');
Route::post('/prefcard/maker-search-intervenant', 'SelectCRController@postSearchIntervenant');

Route::get('/intervenant', function () {return view('intervenant');});
Route::get('/api/intervenant/{id?}', 'IntervenantController@index');
Route::post('/api/intervenant', 'IntervenantController@store');
Route::post('/api/intervenant/{id?}', 'IntervenantController@update');
Route::delete('/api/intervenant/{id?}', 'IntervenantController@destroy');

Route::get('/utilisateur', function () {return view('utilisateur');});
Route::get('/api/utilisateur/{id?}', 'UtilisateurController@index');
Route::post('/api/utilisateur', 'UtilisateurController@store');
Route::post('/api/utilisateur/{id?}', 'UtilisateurController@update');
Route::delete('/api/utilisateur/{id?}', 'UtilisateurController@destroy');

Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

//Route::auth();
```

***app.blade.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***UPDATE***

Now and with some modifications the error disappeared but the scripts are not working at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Selection de Compte-Rendu</div>

                <div class="panel-body"> Selectionnez le client:
                  <input  id="intervenant-name"  type="text" class="form-control pd-l-50" placeholder="Recherche par nom d'entreprise">


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery-1.12.4.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>
<script>
(function () {
    src = "/prefcard/maker-search-intervenant";
    $("#intervenant-name").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                        dataType: "json",
                        data:
                        {
                            term: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            response(data);
                        }
            });
        },
        min_length: 2,
        select: function (event, ui)
        {
                //console.log(ui.item.value);return false;
            var test = ui.item.value ? ui.item.value : '';
            if (test != '')
            {
                var url = '/prefcard/maker-search-intervenant';
                var formAutocomplete = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">' +
                        '<input type="text" name="term" value="' + ui.item.value + '" />' +
                        '</form>');
                $('body').append(formAutocomplete);
                formAutocomplete.submit();
            }
          }
    });
})();
</script>
@endsection

@yield('javascript')
```

Comment: Can we take a look at `layout/app.blade.php` template ?

Comment: I did it in the main subject.
You think there's something to do in it ?

Comment: Are you using `view.js`? What exactly is the challenge you are facing?

Comment: What is view.js ?
ps: I solved my problem by creating a personnalised app.blade.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I made a special "app.blade.php" just for the specified view and put all my scripts in it.
Not very beautiful, but It's working.

Answer (score 1):

1) You have a Vuejs error (add tag plz). Looks like you need to move script tags out of vuejs container.

2) `!DOCTYPE html` must be at the top of your document, not in the middle.

Comment: Do you have demo page to have a look? What is not working? You can add screenshots.

Comment: Now and with some modifications the error disappeared but the scripts are not working at all. 
I put the modified code above.

Comment: Please explain, what is not working exactly. It's hard to understand.

Comment: Normally, when I tap two letters minimum in the autocomplete field, I'll have a list corresponding to words containing these two letters. But in my case it's not working.
Compared to the previous code, I have everything in place, no more error, but it's not proposing me the list.

Comment: Well, debug it. Look at network activity of your browser to watch the response if it is correct.

Comment: That's strange, I have a good response from the database, but nothing is displayed under the field.

Comment: Check server response (if it is a normal json over http), then debug js. Sorry, I give up. Good luck with debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll continue to search. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Blade is powerful to "inject" your view into a skeletonized html page. If you need some clean way to call your layout/app.blade.php, I made an example right below :

**layout/app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    @yield('links')
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
    <!-- Here is the perfect place for the javascript libraries that you think will be used in ANY page -->
    <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- for example if you use jQuery -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- same if you need Bootstrap-Twitter-3 in any pages -->

    <!-- And then, your specific scripts are hooked below -->
    @yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Then, it is as simple as it looks to "inject" your content inside your `<body>` tag, like following :

**selectcr.blade.php** (juste an example)

```
@extends('layout.app')

<!-- Some additionnals css, specific to this page -->
@section('links')
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
@ensection

@section('title')
My awesome title
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3>Greetings user !</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" />
                <button type="submit">Go !</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
    alert('This is my custom javascript !');
</script>
@endsection
```

So, whenever Blade encounters a `@section` tags, it automatically injects its content right inside the place it belongs, meaning in every `@yield` that represent this section.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Move `@yield('javascript')` out of the section put if after the `@endsection` tag, you could also just use `@end`.

Comment out all scripts within your section Tag also! because this is what the error is saying.

Comment: I tried to move '@yeld' out of the section and it didn't work, when i delete '@endsection' then js works but now, the top bar is below the autocomplete filed i don't understand why ?

Comment: Comment out all the scripts within the section tag and see what that does

Answer (score 0):

TRY:
All your script code should be inside

`@section('scripts') .... @endsection.`

And also please close content section before your javascript.